# Is there a way to include contents of a file in Python as code (compile-time)?

Tags: python

I am using a 3rd party application's Python integration where Python code is stored internally in binary files. So I want to separate the code from it. I could create a module but the code I need to include doesn't function on its own, as it includes locals only valid in that context, etc.

I am basically looking for a copy-paste solution at compile-time.

Is there any way to do this in Python?

Comment: There may be a solution using `execfile()`, but there isn't enough detail to say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's called [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec).

Your code would look like this: `exec your_code_str`. The code is then executed in the current scope.

You could also specify a different scope: `exec your_code_str in globals(), locals()` (those values are the default, so only specify them if they differ)

Note that you can also pass a file object, so if the python code is only a single blob of text right at the end of the binary file you can just seek to the beginning of the code and then pass the file object.

Comment: Thanks, actually I was looking for a `include("filename") kinda solution so tried execfile from the comments and it worked. Thanks alot guys :O

Comment: @JoanVenge: note that there is security implications for using exec.

Comment: Also do you know if execfile accepts relative paths? i.e. say my the script file and the including file is in the same directory, and I want to do `execfile("script.py")`, instead of `path + "script.py"`.

Comment: @Lie: exec or execfile? Also it's only my code if that matters.

Comment: @JoanVenge: both of them, if you exec or execfile a file from untrusted source or from a file that can be tampered with by untrusted users then they will be able to execute arbitrary code with your own program's permission and snoop into and modify your program's variables. Even if you only load your own code, there's no saying that the user or malicious program wouldn't attempt to replace the file with a malicious file. You had to design a way to ensure that it is only your own file that could possibly get executed.

Comment: I see what you mean. This is only for internal company use. Don't think I should worry about this :O